# Static changes by saving of web page as "web page complete"

Tags: save, browser, html-tree

I save a web site using Firefox 33.0 as "Web Page, Complete".

The problem is, the html tree of the main html file is changed **statically**.
Before saving there was something like that:

```
Stuff before
<form name="test1>
inner stuff
</form>
Stuff after
```

After saving it looks follow:

```
Stuff before
<form name="test1"></form>
inner stuff
Stuff after
```

I tried Google Chrome and IE. The same thing.

If I save it as "Web Page, HTML Page only", the html tree is saved properly.

What issue could it be?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "Save as" > "Web Page, Complete" feature, does not save invalid html. The invalid html is modified on save so that it becomes valid.

I don't know what your [inner stuff] is, so I don't know how it is offending, but you can try this for instance with placing a block level element inside an inline element.

```
 <span><div>Hello</div><span>
```

becomes

```
 <span><span><div>Hello</div>
```

while

```
 <div><div>Hello</div></div>
```

stays the same.

In this example the offending elements are pushed outside the container, to make the markup valid.